Error building Node.js addon with N-API on Windows: "napi.h: No such file or directory"
I'm trying to create a simple Node.js addon using N-API on Windows. My goal is to output "hello world". However, I'm encountering an error when trying to build the addon. I followed the standard instructions, but I'm getting the following error during the build process:
  nothing.c
  win_delay_load_hook.cc
  nothing.vcxproj -> C:\Users\79832\my-addon\build\Release\\nothing.lib
  addon.cpp
C:\Users\79832\my-addon\src\addon.cpp(2,10): error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'napi.h': No such file or directory [C:\Users\79832\my-addon\build\addon.vcxproj]
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\79832\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:216:23)
gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:519:28)
gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:294:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19045
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\79832\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "build"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\79832\my-addon
gyp ERR! node -v v20.16.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v10.2.0
gyp ERR! not ok

binding.gyp:
{
  "targets": [
    {
      "target_name": "addon",
      "sources": [ "src/addon.cpp" ],
      "include_dirs": [
        "<!(node -p \"require('node-addon-api').include\")"
      ],
      "dependencies": [
        "<!(node -p \"require('node-addon-api').gyp\")"
      ]
    }
  ]
}

addon.cpp:
#include <node_api.h>
#include <napi.h>

Napi::String HelloWorld(const Napi::CallbackInfo& info) {
    Napi::Env env = info.Env();
    return Napi::String::New(env, "Hello, world!");
}

Napi::Object Init(Napi::Env env, Napi::Object exports) {
    exports.Set(Napi::String::New(env, "hello"), Napi::Function::New(env, HelloWorld));
    return exports;
}

NODE_API_MODULE(addon, Init)


I'm trying to create a simple Node.js addon using N-API on Windows. My goal is to output "hello world". However, I'm encountering an error when trying to build the addon. I followed the standard instructions, but I'm getting the following error during the build process:
